# In MQ v6 api - how to stop MQQueue get() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, ibm-mq, interrupt

I'm writing a simple Java application using MQ v6 API classes 
Right now I'm able to browse a remote queue in while cycle. This program runs as windows service, and must be interrupted then the service stops. First i'm setting waitInterval=MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED, but MQMessage.get() prevents breaking of the cycle. Then i'm setting waitInterval=5000 and catch MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE. Is this a normal solution or there is a better one?
Here is the code of the reading cycle:

```
public class MessageConsumer {

private MessageListener ml;
private MQQueue queue;
private Thread sideThread;
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MessageConsumer.class);
private static volatile boolean listening = true;

public MessageConsumer(MQQueue queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

public void setMessageListener(MessageListener ml) throws MQException {
    this.ml = ml;
    start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    this.listening = false;
    logger.log(Priority.INFO, "listening = false");
    sideThread.interrupt(); 
    logger.log(Priority.INFO, "set sideThread.interrupt()");     
}

private void listen() throws MQException {
    MQGetMessageOptions getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
    getOptions.options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER + MQC.MQGMO_ALL_SEGMENTS_AVAILABLE + MQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG + MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
    getOptions.waitInterval = 5000;//MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED;
    logger.log(Priority.INFO, "Start of listening");
    int i = 1;
    while (listening) {
        //  try {
        System.out.println("Read message");
        MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
        logger.log(Priority.INFO, "Waiting message: ");
        try {
            queue.get(message, getOptions);
             logger.log(Priority.INFO, "Get message: ");
            if (ml != null) {
                ml.onMessage(message);
            }
        } catch (MQException e) {
            if (e.reasonCode == e.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) {
                System.out.println("no more message available or retrived");
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    logger.log(Priority.INFO, "End of listening");
}

private void start() throws MQException {
    sideThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
    listen();
    } catch (MQException mqex) {
    logger.log(Priority.ERROR, "A WebSphere MQ Error occured : Completion Code "
    + mqex.completionCode + " Reason Code "
    + mqex.reasonCode, mqex);

    mqex.printStackTrace();

    }
    }
    });
    sideThread.start();
    try {
    sideThread.join();


    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    logger.log(Priority.INFO, "MessageConsumer.start()", ex);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MessageConsumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
         }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Using a 5s timeout is not a very nice way of doing it - I expect you agree with this or you would not have asked the question.

The answer is to use a thread. Before your call to the `get` method, inform the thread that you are calling `get`. When the get completes inform it that you are finished. You must also arrange for the thread to be informed when the service stops. When the thread is told that the service must stop it should interrupt the thread (and therefore your `get`).

Here's an example. Create one of these and start it running. Whenever you are about to call `get` call `register()`. When `get` completes call `deRegister()`. When the service is to stop call `stop()` and all your outstanding `get`s will be interrupted.

```
public class StopWatcher implements Runnable {
  // Use a blocking queue to signal the stop - that way we avoid sleeps etc.
  BlockingQueue stop = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);
  // All threads that need to be interrupted.
  Set<Thread> needInterrupting = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Thread> ();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      // Block on the stop queue - i.e. wait until stop is called.
      stop.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      // Just ignore it - we need to interrupt everyone anyway whether we have been interrupted or not.
    }
    // Interrupt everuone who needs it.
    for ( Thread t : needInterrupting ) {
      t.interrupt();
    }
  }

  // Register for interruption.
  public void register () {
    needInterrupting.add(Thread.currentThread());
  }

  // Register for interruption.
  public void deRegister () {
    needInterrupting.remove(Thread.currentThread());
  }

  // Stop.
  public void stop () {
    // Post something in the queue to trigger the stop process.
    stop.add(this);
  }

}
```

On second thoughts - you could probably do it without a thread if you are already multithreaded.

```
public class StopWatcher {
  // All threads that need to be interrupted.
  Set<Thread> needInterrupting = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Thread> ();

  // Register for interruption.
  public void register () {
    needInterrupting.add(Thread.currentThread());
  }

  // Register for interruption.
  public void deRegister () {
    needInterrupting.remove(Thread.currentThread());
  }

  // Stop.
  public void stop () {
    // Interrupt everuone who needs it.
    for ( Thread t : needInterrupting ) {
      t.interrupt();
    }
    needInterrupting.clear();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes i dont'want using waitInterval=5000, i'm prefer MQWI_UNLIMITED.

Comment: I'm testing your solution and when call register get exception:Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Comment: @user2131064 - Ah yes - `ConcurrentSkipListSet` needs `Comparable`. Try `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Boolean>())`.

Answer (score 0):

Goods morning OldCurmudgeoned. I'm confused. I'm little modifed your code:

```
package threadUtil;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet;

public class StopWatcher2 {
    // All threads that need to be interrupted.
//  Set<Thread> needInterrupting = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Thread> ();

    Set<Thread> needInterrupting = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Thread>(new Comparator<Thread>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Thread o1, Thread o2) {
            Long l1 = o1.getId();
            Long l2 = o2.getId();

            if (l1.equals(l2)) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    });

    // Register for interruption.
    public void register() {
        needInterrupting.add(Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println("register thread: name=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    // Register for interruption.
    public void deRegister() {
        needInterrupting.remove(Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println("deRegister thread: name=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    // Stop.
    public void stop() {
        // Interrupt everuone who needs it.
        String name;
        long id;
        for (Thread t : needInterrupting) {
            name = t.getName();
            id = t.getId();
            t.interrupt();
            System.out.println("interrupt thread: name=" + name + ": id= " + id);
        }
        needInterrupting.clear();
    }
}
```

And write a simple model (instead mqqueue work with socket - for modelling a problem). All code:

```
package multithreadingportlistener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import threadUtil.StopWatcher;


public class MultithreadingPortListener {


    private class ThreadComparator extends Thread implements Comparator<Thread> {

        public ThreadComparator(Thread t) {
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Thread o1, Thread o2) {
            if (o1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(o2.getName())) {
                return 0;

            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        MultiThreadedServer server = new MultiThreadedServer(9000);

        new Thread(server).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20 * 100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(
                "Stopping Server");
        server.stop();
    }
}


/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package multithreadingportlistener;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import threadUtil.StopWatcher2;

public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable {

    protected int serverPort = 8080;
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    protected boolean isStopped = false;
    protected Thread runningThread = null;
    private StopWatcher2 sw;

    public MultiThreadedServer(int port) {
        this.serverPort = port;
        sw = new StopWatcher2();

    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        openServerSocket();
        while (!isStopped()) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;

            try {
                sw.register();
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("wair accept().");
                sw.deRegister();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (isStopped()) {
                    System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
                    return;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Error accepting client connection", e);
            }
            new Thread(
                    new WorkerRunnable(
                    clientSocket, "Multithreaded Server")).start();
        }
        System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
    }

    private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.isStopped = true;
        sw.stop(); // special instead  this.serverSocket.close() for modelling as mqqueue

    }

    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 8080", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The serverSocket.accept() also as MqQueue.get is not end.
How resolved this truble?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon. I'm have a trouble